# Is there any way to separate data/cookies/cache so each browser windows has its own and clearing one doesn't effect the other?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I use Chrome for web browsing.
BUT I also use it to run specific work applications.
To prevent comtamination/distractions, I open
3 chrome windows..totally seperate on windows10....
(Just to be clear, I'm talking about windows...not tabs in the same window)

When i clear everything(cookies, data cache etc) on the one i use for 
web browsing, its effects the other 2 windows and causes me to have to jump
through hoops(login, change some settings etc) to get them back to where they were.

Is there any way to 'set it up' to avoid this?

I 'suppose' I could use Chrome and maybe another type of browser at the same
time to get around this.

Comment: Use an incognito window for the ones you don't want to keep cookies, history, etc, incognito windows uses it own database and is cleared when the window is closed.

Comment: maybe the multiple profiles will be the solution for you: https://pureinfotech.com/add-new-user-profiles-google-chrome/

Comment: @Moab - Doesn't Incognito use a single session, even the case of multiple windows, since you can make a new window by dragging and dropping a session tab?

Answer (score 0):

One way I do it is with [multiple profiles](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en). Technically it works like different "people" using the same Windows account.

This separate the data for each browser window and the separate profiles means that clearing one does not affect the other. You end up with effectively what you have now, but can easily open the "other person" using the built-in "people" icon in the top right corner of the browser.

> #### Add a person or profile
>
> 1. On your computer, open Chrome.
> 2. At the top right, click Profile [image: Profile].
> 3. Click Manage people.
> 4. Click Add person.
> 5. Choose a name and a photo.
> 6. Click Save. A new window will open and ask you to turn on sync.

Then

> #### Switch to another person or profile
>
> 1. On your computer, open Chrome.
> 2. At the top right, click Profile [image: Profile].
> 3. Choose the person or profile you want to switch to.

None of the logins from one window work in the other and everything else is separated too. If you click a link in an email it will open in the *last used* browser window which, if it is not the one you are logged into a site with, can result in you seeing a "login" page making you close that tab, go to the *right* browser window, then back to the email to click again. I consider that a small inconvenience to separate things.

Comment: Windows Sandbox could in theory be used to separate individual instances of Chrome (in Incognito mode).

Comment: @Ramhound I can see that it *should* work, but I've not tried Sandbox to know the technicalities or set up or caveats. Is it simply setup Sandbox and you have all the host programs available but on closing you loose all the data from the sandbox session or can it be more permanent?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome for general use

[Chromium 32 bit](https://chromium.woolyss.com/download/en/) for special use A

[Chromium 64 bit](https://chromium.woolyss.com/download/en/) for special use B

Each makes separate profiles for a given Windows user, so you do not need to make multiple Windows users.